# datagridview checkboxcolumn null reference/values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DGV as per the following pic;

[image: Error]

I want to turn a mod on/off with the checkboxes - I have this code so far;

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)row.Cells[3].Value == false)
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("clicked");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("un-clicked");
            }
        }
    }
```

But it returns a nullexception error. I have tried a way that I found on here (a similar problem) but it made it so that when I ticked the box, it enabled/disabled a popup message when the other boxes/buttons are pressed.

At the moment(as a test for now...mods will come later), I want a "Ticked" popup box to appear when I tick a box and then an "un-ticked" popup box when it is un-ticked.

So (eventually) for the code above, I would like Godmode (column index 2) to be switched on for that client only when the box is ticked, and Godmode off when it is un-ticked

This simple thing is driving me mad, so any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: What line is the error on.

Comment: if ((bool)row.Cells[3].Value == false)

Comment: If you're going for the third column, it would need to be index 2. Assuming you have set your column to a `CheckboxColumn`, use `Selected` to retrieve its state. Your `if` statement might look like this: `if ((bool)row.Cells[2].Selected == false)`

Comment: @TestWell No, do not use `Selected`. [DataGridViewCell.Selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates if the cell is selected, not the `Checked` state,

Comment: If you have not bound any data to your `DataGridView`, then the *first* time you access a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, it's `Value` will be null (which still displays as unchecked), hence your NullException.

Comment: hi - sorry for the long delay...just got a new pc and had to install everything all over again lol. I have tried and tried with this with many google searches but I can't figure it out. I have tried various ways but they either give the null exception or just do nothing. I don't know what to do now. The very annoying thing is that I skyped a friend who did manage to get it working with lambda expressions but I cant ffro the life of me remember how he did it. I can't get a hold of him now